# Get return Value from Object.keys

Tags: javascript

I have a function that searches an object, to see if a value exist in it but I can't get the value from it when I try to log it.

```
searchValue(object,value){
    let valueExists = Object.keys(object).find(key => object[key].valueID === value );
    console.log(valueExists);   
}
```

Comment: What are you calling this with - what's an example input and output?

Comment: What is `valueID`? If you are expecting a boolean use  `Object.values(object).some(v => v === value)`

Comment: @adiga No, it won't. It'll return the key that have `value` as its `valueID` property.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk I'm talking about the expected output OP is asking: *"if a value exist in it but I can't get the value from it when I try to log it"*

Comment: @adiga Based on what he's console.logging, I assumed it was just poorly worded, and the "value" he's looking to return is the key.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk It's not poetry to interpret it many ways :) OP hasn't clarified what `valueID` is, what the input and expected output look like. Voting to close as No [mcve]

Comment: @adiga It's not poetry, but English isn't everyone's first language, so I always err on trying to understand what people *meant* rather than taking every word written literally.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk that wasn't my intention. English isn't my first language either (rather my fourth language). Developers communicate through code. I wouldn't even care if the writing was completely gibberish as long as the post has input, expected output and a problem statement. I'm not voting to close because of the grammar is bad but this is not MCVE. Besides, OP said `some` worked for them anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Object(o).values` like :

```
let valueExists = Object.values(object).find(val => val === value )
console.log(valueExists)
```

JS Example :

```js
function searchValue(object, value) {

  let valueExists = Object.values(object).find(val => val == value)
  console.log(valueExists)
}

let user = {
  id: 12,
  name: "aaa",
  email: "aaaa@domain.com",

}

searchValue(user, "aaa")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have value (as `searchValue` parameter) you don't need to "get" value because you already have it (below I simplify your implementation)

```js
function searchValue(object, value) {
  return Object.values(object).includes(value);  
}

let obj = {a: "xx", b: "yy"};
let val = "yy"

if(searchValue(obj,val)) {
    console.log("the object value exist and is:", val);
}
```

If you interest to find keys which are associated with value try this

```js
function searchKeys(object, value) {
  return Object.keys(object).filter(k=>object[k]==value);  
}

let obj = {a: "xx", b: "yy", c:"xx"};
let val = "xx"


console.log("Keys contains 'xx' value:", searchKeys(obj,val));
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using Object entries and looping with forEach for value

```js
function searchValue(object,value){   
    Object.entries(object).forEach(v => {
      if(v.indexOf(value) !== -1) console.log("valueExists") 
    });   
}

let test = {
  id : 11,
  name: 'abc',
  location: 'usa'
}

searchValue(test, 11)
```